# perl DBI->connect pops "no route to host" although i can pick host

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi, dbd

I have this perl script

**wrapper.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use DBI;

# input params
my $end;
my $start;
my $url;
my @IP;
my $host = "localhost";
my $dbname = "flows";
my $username;
my $pass;
GetOptions      ("s|start=s" => \$start,
                 "e|end=s" => \$end,
                 "r|url=s" => \$url,
                 "ip|iplist=s" => \@IP,
                 "h|host=s" => \$host,
                 "db|dbname=s" => \$dbname,
                 "u|username=s" => \$username,
                 "p|pass=s" => \$pass);



# connect and send request to database

 my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host, $username, $pass, {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

When i run

```
./wrapper.pl -h 10.0.0.3
```

I get :

```
DBI connect('dbname=flows;host=10.0.0.3','',...) failed: could not connect to server: No route to host
Is the server running on host "10.0.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I can ping the server and also it should accept connections on 5432.
May I get this message because of bad login credentials?

Comment: What about `psql -h 10.0.0.3 flows` from the same user account and host? Same result?

Comment: Redundant use of the concatenation operator: `"DBI:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$host"` -- interpolate your scalar variables.

Comment: `No route to host` sounds like a message from OS itself. (I don't know if there's any way to specify a proxy, but if there is and if you did, the host in question could be the proxy.)

Comment: Ahh, I got it. I had wrong $dbname. I also edited my script in way TLP suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should `use DBD::Pg;` after `use DBI;`

Secondly add `DBI->errstr` for more proper error

> my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host,
>   $username, $pass, {'RaiseError' => 1}) or die DBI->errstr;

Third you should be able to connect to psql from commandline before triyng from DBI

`psql -h 10.0.0.3 -U username -d dbname -p 5432` (Please check syntax)